# Does @Cacheable annotated methods execute when the actual data is modified?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

I am building a RESTful web service that can be consumed by a browser or another web service.
I am willing to reduce the bandwidth through caching, however i want the method to be executed and send the actual data only if it's different than the last modified cache.

From my understanding of the `@Cacheable` annotation, the method is only executed once and the output is cached until the cache expires .

Also `@CachePut` executes everytime and updates the cache but does it send the cache again even if it's not updated?

Summary is: I need the client to be able to send the last modified date of it's cache and only get a new data if it has been modified.

Also how does Spring handle the client side caching and if-modified-since headers? does i need to save the last modified time or it is automatically handled?

Comment: Use the observer pattern. If the value is updated, replace the one in the cache with the new. And always return the one in the cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to do it by yourself.

You need to annotate your "fetch" method with `@Cacheable`([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html)) and then, annotate "update" method with `@CacheEvict` ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html)) in order to "drop" your cache. So when you would fetch your data next time after its modification, it will be fresh.

Alternatively, you can create another method with `@CacheEvict` and manually call it from "update" method.

Answer (score 0):

The cache related  annotations (`@Cacheable`, `@CacheEvict` etc) will only deal with the cache being maintained by application. Any http response header like [last-modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified) etc has to be managed seperately. Spring MVC provides a handy way to deal with it ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html#checkNotModified-long-)).
The logic to calculate the last modified time has to be obviously application specific.

An example of its usage would be

```
MyController {

    @Autowire
     CacheService cacheService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "/testCache", method = RequestMethod.GET)
         public String myControllerMethod(WebRequest webRequest, Model model, HttpServletResponse response) {
            long lastModified = // calculate as per your logic and add headers to response
            if (request.checkNotModified(lastModified)) {
              // stop processing

              return null;
            } else {  

              return cacheService.getData(model);
            }
        }


    @Component
    public class CacheService{

        @Cacheable(value = "users", key = "#id")
        public String getData(Model model) {
            //populate Model
            return "dataview";
        }
```